# Display xml data into html page

Tags: html, css, xml

i want to get data from xml file and display it into html.
Which is the best and easiest method to display xml data in html page ?

Comment: Are you using server-client technology? or you are looking for client solution only?

Comment: no, only client that xml is present in client desktop not in server.

Comment: So what is wrong with just open it with the browser?

Comment: actually when i open it through browser then it will display tag also. and i want display only data in a proper style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use XSLT for this job. XSLT is a language that is designed to transform documents from xml to xml. This is very usefull, because xhtml is an xml language. That means that you can convert xml to xhtml using XSLT.

XSLT can be used both serverside and clientside, but beware of the clientside solution. Some browers does not support it, and some only supports older versions wihch might lead to different results.

You can check out this tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

Comment: While the answer is ok - try to avoid w3schools references since many of their content is outdated/contains mistakes/better tehcnology exists nowadays and gives bad examples to people trying to learn new subjects on the web.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$xml = $your_xml_string;

try { //try to make it formated. DOMDocument class must be available.
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadXML($xml);
    $doc->formatOutput = true;
    $xml = $doc->saveXML();
} catch (Exception $exc) { }

// parese as html
echo htmlspecialchars($xml);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use JQuery. You can easily parse XML files and display the content where you wish.

Have a look here > [jQuery.parseXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

and here > [Example](http://papermashup.com/parse-xml-with-jquery/)